# What are average advertising banner widths?

Tags: css, advertising

Many websites have advertising, do people know what the general/average/standard width of advertising areas and banner widths are?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

[Google's banners](https://www.google.com/adsense/static/en_GB/AdFormats.html) are probably a good standard to start from.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the most common standard sizes here: [Wikipedia: Web banner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_banner)

As the height is easier to vary than the width in a layout, you will often find advertisers using variations where a standard width is chosen, like for example 250, and different heights are combined with that, like 250x125, 250x250, 250x375.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the most common standard sizes here: [Wikipedia: Web banner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_banner)